# How to use a for loop in this Bernoulli exercise in R?

Tags: r, distributions, econometrics, standardization, bernoulli-distribution

I have a (for me) very difficult exercise, where I want to ask you guys for help as I am still a newbie on R. (But I'm getting there!)
So my question looks like this:

Given Bernoulli distribution with p=0.78
For each sample size n simulate r = 10,000 draws with a for loop from that Bernoulli distribution with p = 0.78 then calculate the standardized sample mean for each of these draw. Replicate all four panels from Figure 2.9 See Figure 2.9 attached to this.

So I know I have to use
`rbinom()`
for this.
But that's it. I really appreciate you guys help on this one.

[image]

(From Stock & Watson (2015), *Introduction to Econometrics*, 3rd Ed., Fig. 2.9)

Comment: Please add the 'self-study' tag if this is homework problem.

Comment: Hi it's not a homework. I am solving exercises from different high schools I find online to improve myself :)

Comment: `n <- 2; p <- 0.78; r <- 100000; simdata <- rbinom(r,n,p)` will give you simulated data for the first case, without the need for a for-loop.  Change `n` for the others

Comment: @Henry: That code does not simulate Bernoulli values --- it simulates binomial values with a size larger than one.  Whilst the ultimate result is the same, presumably the exercise is constructed to show the result on Bernoulli values.

Comment: If your goal is to do this simulation as intended by the author of the book in which you found the problem, then you need to say what kinds of loop structure you are expected to use. @Henry's code uses an internal loop to make binomial variates from Bernoulli ones. Beyond internal loops, there are various kinds of loops you can write using `for` and `replicate`. Can you give us a clue about the kinds of loops you are trying to master? Is a `for` loop the only option?

Comment: Hi Bruce, this exercise requires to use a for loop.

Comment: I recognize this Figure; it is from Stock & Watson "Introduction to Econometrics".

Comment: @ColorStatistics Looking at the 3rd Edition, this is Figure 2.9 in a section about the Central Limit Theorem

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question once you have answers. If you feel you must change something, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327142/1864816. And please remember to give proper attribution to quoted text & reproduced figures.

Answer (score 4):

The instruction in the exercise to use a loop is bad advice.  The `rbinom` function is already capable of simulating vectors of values, so there is no need for a loop.  The simplest thing to do here is to create an $r \times N$ matrix of simulated Bernoulli random variables taking $N=100$ so that you have enough sample size to meet the requirements of the four specified values of $n$.  Assuming you don't mind having nested simulations (which is not a problem) you then have all the simulated values you need to construct the figures.  Here is some simple code to generate a "reproducible" matrix of simulated Bernoulli random variables.  (Note that you can also use the `sample.int` function to efficiently simulate Bernoulli random variables.)  It will not give you the exact outcomes used in the graphs in that book, but it will nonetheless give you reproducible simulated values.

```
#Set parameters
N    <- 100
r    <- 10000
PROB <- 0.78

#Create matrix for simulated values
set.seed(1)
SIMULATIONS <- matrix(rbinom(r*N, size = 1, prob = PROB), nrow = r, ncol = N)
colnames(SIMULATIONS) <- sprintf('Sample[%s]', 1:N)
```

Once you have simulated the matrix `SIMULATIONS` you then have $r$ rows of simulated values for $N$ sample values.  You can obtain the relevant simulations of the sample means by using the `rowMeans` function on the relevant subsets of the matrix.  You can then use appropriate plotting functions to construct the required plots.  This gives similar results to the graphs you have shown.

```
#Create matrix of standardised sample means
STD.MEANS <- matrix(0, nrow = R, ncol = 4)
colnames(MEANS) <- c('n[2]', 'n[5]', 'n[25]', 'n[100]')
STD.MEANS[, 1] <-   sqrt(2)*(rowMeans(SIMULATIONS[, 1:2])   - PROB)/sqrt(PROB*(1-PROB))
STD.MEANS[, 2] <-   sqrt(5)*(rowMeans(SIMULATIONS[, 1:5])   - PROB)/sqrt(PROB*(1-PROB))
STD.MEANS[, 3] <-  sqrt(25)*(rowMeans(SIMULATIONS[, 1:25])  - PROB)/sqrt(PROB*(1-PROB))
STD.MEANS[, 4] <- sqrt(100)*(rowMeans(SIMULATIONS[, 1:100]) - PROB)/sqrt(PROB*(1-PROB))

#Plot the histograms
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
hist(STD.MEANS[, 1], prob = TRUE, col = "skyblue2", xlim = c(-5, 5), 
     main = '(n = 2)', xlab = 'Standardised Sample Mean')
curve(dnorm(x), add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
hist(STD.MEANS[, 2], prob = TRUE, col = "skyblue2", xlim = c(-5, 5), 
     main = '(n = 5)', xlab = 'Standardised Sample Mean')
curve(dnorm(x), add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
hist(STD.MEANS[, 3], prob = TRUE, col = "skyblue2", xlim = c(-5, 5), 
     main = '(n = 25)', xlab = 'Standardised Sample Mean')
curve(dnorm(x), add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
hist(STD.MEANS[, 4], prob = TRUE, col = "skyblue2", xlim = c(-5, 5), 
     main = '(n = 100)', xlab = 'Standardised Sample Mean')
curve(dnorm(x), add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Ben. I was already wondering about the for loop. Didn't make much sense to me either. But could you anyways tell me a solution WITH a for loop? I am really weak at those.

Comment: Please bear in mind that it is best to learn to *avoid* loops whenever possible.  With that caveat in mind, you could generate the matrix with a ```for``` loop as: ```SIMULATIONS <- matrix(0, nrow = r, ncol = N); for (i in 1:r) { SIMULATIONS[i,] <- rbinom(N, size = 1, prob = PROB) }```.

Comment: I will bear that in mind! So when I have this huge vector now did i calculate the standardized sample mean of each draw without using the formula for it? I don't really know how to plot now with this matrix :/

Comment: I still don't get the solution....

Comment: Hi Ben, I mean I have got it so far. But I don‘t know how to plot it now using rowmeans. I used rowmeans on my dataframe giving me the means for each row. But I struggle plotting this now.

Answer (score 3):

To begin, I agree with @Ben's(+1) statements about avoiding explicit
loops when possible. I have used `for` loops because they seem
to be required for your exercise.

Standardization is done outside the `for` loop, using means and standard deviations from the 10,000 averages `a`.

Here is a simulation in R for the case $n = 25.$

```
set.seed(121)
n = 25;  p = 0.78
r = 10^4;  a = numeric(r)
for(i in 1:r) {
  a[i] = mean(rbinom(n, 1, .78))  
  }
mean(a);  sd(a)
z = (a-mean(a))/sd(a)
cp = seq(-5.75, 5.75, length=13)
hdr = "n=25: Standardized Value of Sample Average"
hist(z, prob=T, br=cp, ylim=c(0,.4), col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dnorm(x), add=T, lwd=2)
```

[image]

*Note about making histograms:* I have used standard graphics from the base of R to make
the histogram and superimpose the standard normal density curve.
Even though $r = 10,000$ means have been generated so that `a`
has $r$ values, there are not many *unique* values in `a`--fifteen
in my simulation (some relatively rare). If the tied values are not equitably proportioned
among the histogram bins, you get some strange-looking histograms
that make the values of `z` look far from normal. By choosing 13 bins
I got a nice plot. (Roughly speaking, there are two `z`-values per bin, with some empty bins at the ends.)

```
length(unique(a))
[1] 15
table(a)
a
0.44 0.48 0.52 0.56  0.6 0.64 0.68 0.72 0.76  0.8 0.84 0.88 0.92 0.96    1 
   1   12   22   86  212  459  847 1381 1795 1914 1591 1037  495  123   25
```